# Best Way to Add target="_blank" to HTML Using PHP

Tags: php, html, replace

I am pulling in HTML from a database and displaying it on a webpage using PHP. Lets just say that the people who will be putting in the HTML are not very experiences and will probably struggle with just creating things such as links. I need all the links to open in new pages (which I will do by adding `target="_blank"` inside the `<a>` tags. Now the question: what is the best way to do this?

As an example the following HTML in the database:

```
<a href="www.google.com">link</a>
```

Should be outpus as:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">link</a>
```

I currently have this line to do what I want:

```
$text = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 target="_blank">', $text);
```

But as I know from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1916721) answer and many others on SO, regex and HTML is not advised. Is there a better way? Using a HTML/XML parser, etc. seems over the top for such a simple operation.

Comment: Never use regexes on html, especially if you're trying to CHANGE the html. Use DOM, and then it's a simple `$node->setAttribute('target', '_blank');`

Comment: Is javascript out of the question?

Comment: I am by no means and expert on web security, but storing and retrieving HTML from a database sounds like a bad idea. A user could easily submit malicious JavaScript and other code. I hope you know what you are doing :\

Comment: @MarcB Never say never...

Comment: @jason: so all of the forums and blogs and CMS systems out there are a bad idea? Databases don't care what you're storing in them. it's just data. What's dangerous is HOW you get that into the database.

Comment: @Jason The database is basically a new CMS and is edited by the same people who were writing the actual PHP before. If they really wanted to be malicious they would have already done so :).

Comment: @MarcB Could you create an answer with a more descriptive answer to this problem using DOM?

Comment: @MarcB That was essentially my point. If any user with privileges to submit to the database can write any HTML, what's stopping them from placing some `<script>` tags in there? I know that CMSs have ways of preventing this. I was just reminding him that it could be abused if he's not careful. Also, forums usually avoid HTML altogether and instead use a smaller ("weaker") language like BBCode or Markdown.

Comment: @cabellicar123 Ah then you probably don't have anything to worry about. I thought any user would be able to submit code like a forum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The better way would be doing this in Javascript and letting the client handle it. if you are using jquery it would be as easy as :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

or in vanilla javascript:

```
 window.onload = function() {
     var a = document.getElementsByTagName('A');
     for (var i =0, l=a.length; i < l; i++) {
         a[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
     }
 }
```

of if you really need it to be done in PHP:

```
$html = "YOUR HTML STRING";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$dom = $doc->loadHTML($html);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
   $link->setAttribute('target', '_blank');
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

should work

Comment: So was I lol! I assume it is because the question was not tagged javascript

Comment: That's ridiculous. Anyway I am going to up vote this. I think this is the best solution for above question. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks man. Three different ways. I'm going down the jquery route but the other options were a nice addition.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the first option to work. Vanilla works fine but jquery isn't. See this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CTtS6/.

Comment: Sorry I didn't close the document.ready wrapper correctly. Updated now - http://jsfiddle.net/CTtS6/1/

Answer (score 0):

> But as I know from this answer and many others on SO, regex and HTML is not advised.

Correct

> Is there a better way?

Yes. Use an HTML parser.

> Using a HTML/XML parser, etc. seems over the top for such a simple operation.

"Adding `target="_blank"` to some links" *sounds* like a simple operation, but the real operation is really "Taking some user input, which might be HTML but is probably tag soup and full of errors, and trying to edit it according to some pre-defined rules".

Use an HTML parser. This is what they are designed for.